# SqlAlchemy Error : Default Value Doesn't exist, but why?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am developing a REST API SERVER using FAST-API with SQLALCHEMY.

But when I try to create some new data Column using request body's data, it keeps returning `Internal Server Error` as shown below. I use email as primary key and put email info when I create it, but the error is not resolved.

```
@router.post("/register/{sns_type}", status_code=200, response_model=Token)
async def register(sns_type: SnsType, reg_info: TestUserRegister, session: Session=Depends(db.session)):
    
    if sns_type == SnsType.email:

        if not reg_info.email or not reg_info.pw:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content=dict(msg="Email and PW must be provided"))
        is_exist = await is_email_exist(reg_info.email)
        if is_exist:
            return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content=dict(msg="EMAIL_EXISTS"))
        
        if not is_company_exist(reg_info.company):
            return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content=dict(msg="No such company exists"))

        hash_pw = bcrypt.hashpw(reg_info.pw.encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
        new_user = User.create(session, auto_commit=True, email=reg_info.email, pw=hash_pw,  Company_ID=Company.get(CompanyName=reg_info.company).CompanyID)
        token = dict(Authorization=f"Bearer {create_access_token(data=UserToken.from_orm(new_user).dict(exclude={'pw'}))}")
        return token

    return JSONResponse(status_code=400, content=dict(msg="Not Supported"))
```

This is my Data Schema.

```
class User(Base, BaseMixin):
    __tablename__ = "User"
    email = Column(String(length=255), primary_key=True)
    pw = Column(String(length=2000), nullable=False)
    usertype = Column(Enum("Admin", "Company-Host", "Company-User", "Developer"), default="Company-User")
    status = Column(Enum("active", "deleted", "blocked"), default="active")
    CompanyID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Company.CompanyID"))
    phone_number = Column(String(length=20), nullable=True, unique=True)
    profile_img = Column(String(length=1000), nullable=True)
    sns_type = Column(Enum("FB", "G", "K", 'N'), nullable=True)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.utc_timestamp(), onupdate=func.utc_timestamp())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkffi.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant debugging details (i.e. the error message) as text in your post as well, images remove the error message from the post context, is hard to read for those that have accessibility issues and aren't really searchable.